# Web service is updated should do I have to update in soapui tool?

Tags: web-services, testing, automation, soapui

I have running Project in SOAPUI. Now webservice is updated with new
more methods.

Should i have to update something or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to soapui 5.0, if it's a SOAP service, then right click on the wsdl in soapui and click on update definition. And select what ever check boxes you want to.

If it's a REST service, then you could right click on the resource under your wadl and add a new child resource. Then you could select what ever type of request it is (GET, POST etc.). You could also add the input parameters there :) These parameters and resouce-name you could find by accessing the  URL of the service in a web browser.